# can't understand in what situation to use want vs wants

Tags: phrases

I have a sentence "Creative mind that want to develop in every possible way"

I reacted to the word "want" and thought it should be "wants" but I don't really know why, or if it's even correct to change it?

I tried to search for an answer but it isn't making my situation any clearer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a sentence.

There is a noun "mind", which is modified by an adjective "creative" and a relative clause "that want to develop in every possible way".  There is no main verb.

Now in this phrase, the relative clause is headed by a pronoun "that", and in this case, the relative pronoun is standing for "mind", a singular noun. So the verb in the relative clause (want) needs to agree, and should have the form "wants".

Some examples

> A dog that has a bone is a happy animal.

Singular dog, so third person singular "has", also the main verb is "is"

> The birds that fly over my house come from Africa.

Plural "birds", the verb "fly" in the relative clause and the main verb "come" are both third person plural.

> A dog that I own is happy.

The relative clause "that I own" has its own subject, and the pronoun "that" is the object of the relative clause. The verb "own" is first person singular, but the main verb "is" is third person singular.

Answer (score 1):

There is the typo in the Subject of the sentence, because such a noun phrase as *creative mind* is impossible in the sentence. The subject should be *creative minds*. So, the sentence is *Creative minds that want to develop in every possible way*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the context of the phrase, but it seems likely to be a typo. It should have been "Creative mind**s**... want", or possibly "[a] Creative mind... want**s**". English verb conjugations are so sparse we usually don't even think about them, sometimes causing confusion one the rare occasion that we do.

In this case the rule is simply that in the present perfect tense, you add an "s" to the end of a singular third-person noun. So, *I, you, we, they,* and *creative minds* (3rd person plural) all **want** to develop. But *he,she,it,* or a *creative mind* (3rd person singular) **wants** to develop.

Also worth noting that this rule is ignored when you negate the verb. So "a creative mind that **wants** to develop" is correct, while "a creative mind that **doesn't want** to develop" is also correct.